# PHP : call property_exists() function inside of the Abstract method called from within the Child class

Tags: php, abstract-class, abstract

I want to create the setProperties() method inside of the Abstract class which looks like this:

```
public function setProperties($array = null) {

        if (!empty($array)) {
            foreach($array as $key => $value) {
                if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
                    $this->{$key} = $value;
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

What I'm not quite sure about is whether I'll be able to use it in the classes that inherit from this Abstract class to set the inherited properties as well as the child class specific.

I'm not sure if I should use any other keyword then $this in the property_exists() function - perhaps there's a way by using late static bindings (static::) keyword?

Comment: Why don't you try it? That should be faster to test than to ask a question here ;) but yes, you will be able to use it like you intend and there is no need for late *static* binding when you deal with non-static attributes.

Comment: Didn't really have the environment ready yet - just wanted to make sure - would normally check rather than ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should basically work. Imagine this simple example what outputs two times `true`:

```
abstract class A {

    protected $var1;

    public function exists1() {
        var_dump(property_exists($this, 'var2'));
    }

}

class B extends A {

    protected $var2;

    public function exists2() {
        var_dump(property_exists($this, 'var1'));
    }
}


$o = new B();

$o->exists1();
$o->exists2();
```

As you can see, `property_exists()` works when the child class is accessing a member from the parent class and vise versa when the parent class is trying to access a member of the child.

That's one of the basic concepts of abstraction. What you are trying to do is absolutely ok. If you get an error anyway, it must be a little overseen detail

Comment: Thanks hek2mgl. I've also just read a comment that isset() function is about 4 times faster than property_exists() so I might use it instead as isset($this->{$key}).

Comment: **Mind** that isset will return false even if the property exists but has a value of NULL. I would **not** use isset for that reason  (knowing that it is faster)

Comment: But there is a difference. `isset` returns false if the property exists but is not initailized or is `null`.

Comment: All that is fine - I only need to know whether the property has physically been defined - value in this case does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

`$this` is instance-specific, and as a result, `property_exists` will work correctly with child classes.

Comment: @hek2mgl Yes, I am. Quite a few libraries work this way, providing a base model with a `populate` method that does something very similar to this. I personally have done this before too, although in the recent past I have taken a much different approach to mapping arrays to objects for better adherence to OOP paradigms.

Comment: Opps! sorry, I read 'will not work correctly' ... my failure ;)